# Bootstrap tab-content conflicts with *ngFor

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some issues with bootstrap and angular 2(TS), I'm trying to make a button that on medium and small widths shows a window button and when you click it displays a list of popular and commented news. My first issue is that the news are always visible even if the tabs are hidden, and second one is that when I click any tab, it only displays the first new.

**Button:**

```
  <button (click)="showNews()" type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#popular-news">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle menu</span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>
  </button>
```

**Tabs:**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="popular-news">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#popular">Popular</a></li>
    <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#commented">Commented</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div #indicator1 class="indicator"></div>
  <div #indicator2 class="indicator"></div>
</div>
```

**Tabs content:**

```
    <section class="best-news tab-content" #bestNews>
      <div id="popular" *ngFor="let notice of news" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="pnew-img">
          <img src="./img/default.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="pnew-title">{{ notice.noticeTitle}}</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="commented" class="tab-pane fade" *ngFor="let notice of news">
        <div class="pnew-img">
          <img src="./img/default.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="pnew-title">{{ notice.noticeTitle }}</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

**TypeScript Code:**

```
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
  pageTitle: string = 'Gaming News';
  errorMessage: string;
  news: INews[];
  @ViewChild('bestNews')menuNews: ElementRef;

  constructor(private _newsData: NewsDataService,
          private elementRef: ElementRef,
          private renderer: Renderer) {}

  showNews(): void {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.menuNews, 'best-news-hidden' false);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._newsData.getNews()
      .subscribe(news => this.news = news,
                 error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have some id issues with your tab content:

```
 <section class="best-news tab-content" #bestNews>
      <div id="popular" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="pnew-img" *ngFor="let notice of news">
          <img src="./img/default.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="pnew-title">{{ notice.noticeTitle}}</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="commented" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class="pnew-img" *ngFor="let notice of news">
          <img src="./img/default.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p class="pnew-title">{{ notice.noticeTitle }}</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Your `*ngFor` were both on the `<div>` that are tab controlled: `id="popular"` and `id="commented"`.  When that was iterated over, you're getting multiple "id" that are the same in the DOM -- no good.  I moved the `*ngFor` down to the content area of the tree on each section, which gives the tab controlled divs their own `id` and allows the looping display within that div.  Let me know if you actually need the tab divs to be looped over.

Comment: Thank you so much! How can I do that when I press the menu button, angular checks if the tab-content is shown, if it is shown then hide it, and if it isn't then show it

Comment: @NikitaCeban there are a couple ways to do that, but the easiest one is to maintain a variable in your component the tracks the view-state of the content and flips on a condition :)